# ".errorClass" of jQuery validate works but the class cannot be found by "hasClass()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

## Problem

I'm not a programmer and I'm trying to do some programming.

I tried to use jQuery-validate plug-in to control the form input, it works perfectly, Bootstrap can even find the ".text-danger" class and change its' color.

However, the ".hasClass()" method just can't.

I put some "console.log()" functions in the for loops which are used to find this class.
The log messages I received every time are "changed", "hasSmall", "noClass".

Have I made mistakes in the JS code?

Please help me out.

## Code

### This is within my HTML form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="signUpUserName" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password </label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="signUpPassword" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="signUpEmail" />
</div>
```

### This is the JavaScript:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var obj = $('[name="'+element.attr('name')+'"]');
    obj.siblings('label').append(error);
},
```

### I have changed some values in the valadate.min.js：

```
$.extend($.validator, {

defaults: {
    messages: {},
    groups: {},
    rules: {},

    errorClass: "text-danger", // I've changed this
    validClass: "text-success", // this
    errorElement: "small", // and this

    focusInvalid: true,
    errorContainer: $([]),
    errorLabelContainer: $([]),
    onsubmit: true,
    ignore: ":hidden",
    ignoreTitle: false,
```

### Also, JS:

```
function changeInputAreaStatus(id) {
    $(id).change(function(id) {
        console.log('changed');
        var errorMessageContainer = $(id).siblings('label');
        if(errorMessageContainer.has('small')){
            console.log('hasSmall');
            if (errorMessageContainer.children('small').hasClass('text-danger')) {
                console.log('hasDangerClass');
                errorMessageContainer.parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-error');
            } else if (errorMessageContainer.children('small').hasClass('text-success')) {
                console.log('hasSucessClass');
                errorMessageContainer.parent().removeClass('has-error');
            } else {
                console.log('noClass');
            }
        }
    });
}
    changeInputAreaStatus('#signUpUserName');
    changeInputAreaStatus('#signUpPassword');
    changeInputAreaStatus('#signUpEmail');
```

Comment: Looks broadly OK to me. Are you definitely looking at the correct element for the style? Can you use your browser debug interface to inspect the DOM at that point and / or test your jQuery expressions?

Comment: Where's the `errorPlacement` function called?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this website is for "professional and enthusiast programmers" but the OP stated, "I'm not a programmer"

Comment: You're making this way more complicated than it needs.  The `errorClass`, `validClass`, and `errorElement` items should be changed via the normal procedure when defining options, **not** by using the `extend` method.  Just set the options by listing them as `key:value` pairs within the `.validate()` method... presumably where you've already placed the `errorPlacement` callback function.  **Have you read the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org) or at least the [SO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) yet?**

Comment: My guess is that you are just not traversing the DOM correctly.  In other words, `errorMessageContainer.children('small')` is not the same place you think it is or the error class is not on its children.  **Normally, the plugin only places the error class on the `label` and the input element.**  Verify the DOM structure by using the DOM inspection tool built into your browser.

Comment: Why on Earth are you trying to manually toggle classes defined by the plugin?  Seriously, about 90% of your code is not needed... for sure I don't understand why you think you would need the `changeInputAreaStatus()` function.  The validation plugin automatically toggles all relevant messages & classes through its options and methods.

Comment: @Sparky I mean I'm not a professional programmer actually, sorry for my English. I've read the documentation in my last holiday, after a trimester, I was too lazy to read it over again. You're right, I just found the `highlight()` and `unhighlight()` function can do better than my `changeInputAreaStatus()` function mentioned in the documentation, they work well. But I still can't make the `hasClass()` function find `text-danger` class, I don't see any troubles in the DOM, `<small>` is `<label>`'s child, `<label>` is `<input>`'s sibling. Overall, my problem is kind of solved but still confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this :

```
var textSuccess = errorMessageContainer.find('.text-success');
if(textSuccess != null && textSuccess.length > 0){
    console.log('hasSucessClass');
}
```

it should help you to verify if errorMessageContainer has a text-success class.

Best regards